# Tag request: [.htaccess] (mod_rewrite, url-rewriting, …)

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

A [.htaccess](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/.htaccess) tag would be suitable for:

- [Canonicalize URLs for static website](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/18440/16414)
- [Suggestions on how to improve this .htaccess file for page load speed](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/4812/16414)

Maybe finer grained tags could be useful, like `mod_rewrite` or `url-rewriting`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've added the tag. Thanks for your suggestion.